# a In a SwiftUI app using Firestore to keep track of users, keep track of the registered users by a sequential user number

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a struct for User:

```
struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: String
    let userNumber: Int
    let email: String

    var firstInitial: String {
        return userName.isEmpty ? "" : String(userName.prefix(1))
    }
}
```

When I create a user, I want to first user to be desgnated with 1, the second with 2 and so on. It seems to me that I need an init for this, but it's not clear to me how to implement that.

I create a user object like this:

```
User(id: NSUUID().uuidString,
     userNumber: ???,
     email: "test@gmail.com")
```

It's not clear to me how to make each successive user know that it in the next user in the sequence and what that next number ought to be.

Comment: There is no product called Firebase datastore. Do you mean [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant Firestore database. I am creating users in a collection called "users" and want to keep track of them sequentially.

Comment: You should consider very carefully if this is an important thing to have in your app because sequential consecutive numbers in Firestore are neither easy nor scalable. But if you must have them, you will need to use a transaction to implement them reliably. Your transaction will have to find the last number, create a new document with the next number, and retry in the event that two clients try to make a document with the same number.  You are almost certainly better off instead using another way of identifying each user, such as a UUID and using a timestamp to order them if needed.